# xorm , difference between Sync and Sync2 functions

Tags: go, go-xorm

The xorm go library has 2 function that appear similar:

```
// Sync the new struct changes to database, this method will automatically add
// table, column, index, unique. but will not delete or change anything.
// If you change some field, you should change the database manually.
func (engine *Engine) Sync(beans ...interface{}) error 

// Sync2 synchronize structs to database tables
func (engine *Engine) Sync2(beans ...interface{}) error
```

(While the Sync2() "docs" doesn't contain the explanation that it will add columns/indexes etc, the implementation does seem to do that too)

What is the difference between these two functions, and when should you use Sync and when should you use Sync2 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at https://gitea.com/xorm/xorm/src/commit/5fafa00043917e1253ebac95b5de29e2f08a569f/engine.go#L1115-L1128 
(which is the `HEAD` of the current `master` branch at the time of writing).

As you can see there, apparently the developers noticed that as well, and deprecated `Sync2` in favor of `Sync`.
So, in short, you simply shouldn't use `Sync2` at all anymore.